# powershell, scheduledtasks, how to list queued instances

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduled task with "Queue a new instance" selected. At some point, I know that an instance is running and that there is (at least) one pending instance waiting in line to run.

I was expecting `Get-ScheduledTask` or `Get-SheduledTaskInfo` to return an array with one line per instance but the only info is that the task is currently running with zero missed runs.

How can I access this information, and if possible, list the pending instances with their info (eg. the time they were triggered)?